# Сортировка многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

```
Array ( 
  [112566] => Array ( [0] => 1415346186 ) 
  [112370] => Array ( [0] => 1415346220 ) 
  [111064] => Array ( [0] => 1415346259 ) 
  [48629]  => Array ( [0] => 1415346287 ) 
)
```

У меня есть такой массив. Как его сортировать по значению ключа 0, от большего к меньшему?

Пробовал такой вариант, но никакой сортировки не происходит:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return ($a[0] - $b[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Почитай про функцию array_multisort(), она поможет.

**Обновление**

Фразу не закончил. Попробовал и что? Что такое $mass_us_v_s ? Почему первым параметром идет не массив? http://www.php.su/array_multisort

С usort функцию напиши нормально

```
function array_sort($a, $b){ 
    if ($a[0] == $b[0]){ return 0; } 
    return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1; 
}
```

Comment: Пробовал:

array_multisort($mass_us_v_s[(int)$_POST['id']][0], SORT_DESC, $mass_us_v_s);

Comment: Фразу не закончил. Попробовал и что? Что такое $mass_us_v_s ? Почему первым параметром идет не массив? http://www.php.su/array_multisort

С usort функцию напиши нормально
function array_sort($a, $b){ 
if ($a[0] == $b[0]){ return 0; } 
return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1; 
}

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
    $param[$key]  = $row[0];
}
array_multisort($param, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```